# Java i/o reading a text while hiding specific words

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, name-hiding

How would you read the following text while hiding the word SECRET each times it appears ?
here is the text :

this line has a secret word.

this line does not have a one.

this line has two secret words.

this line does not have any.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BufferedReadertest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList <String>list = new ArrayList<>();


        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("secretwords.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(sCurrentLine);

                }

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                System.out.println(list.get(i));
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it's not enough clear. try be more specific

Comment: If performance is not an issue (more specifically loading the entire string in memory) just do a replace on the resulting string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm n seeing the need to use an ArrayList.  Replace `SECRET` and print the message when iterating the buffered reader.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("secretwords.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine.replaceAll("SECRET", ""));

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: And how would you remove an entire paragraph if the word "secret" is found. For ex: if you have 4 lines in a paragraph and the word secret is found, the entire paragrph should be removed.

Comment: @InsideHere paragraph or sentence?

Comment: paragraph that contains the word Secret.

Comment: You would need to store the text during each iteration of the StringReader into a StringBuilder.  Once you encountered a blank line, you would then check the content of the StringBuilder and conditionally display.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like

```
System.out.println(list.get(i).replaceAll("SECRET", "******");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(line.indexOf("SECRET") > -1){
   System.out.println("Has Secret");
   continue;
}
```